# Problem with min-width when using percentage in child element

Tags: html, css

So basically the problem is when I want the parent element div to take a minimum width of 30% of the page, it takes 100% of the page. Though, when I change it to width:30%, it performs correctly. Why is min-width not working correctly and what should I do to make it work?

Here is the HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="parent">
         <p> Sign Up Now</p>
        <label for="email">Email:</label> <input placeholder="email"><br />
        <label for="password">Password:</label> <input placeholder="pass"><br />
         <label for="PhoneNumber">PhoneNumber:</label> <input placeholder="PhoneNumber">
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body,html
{
    background-color:red;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}
.parent{
    background-color:yellow;
    width:30%;
    height:50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:40px; 
   }
```

Also I attached it here to visualize what I mean https://jsfiddle.net/u6tvbqj0/2/

Comment: *it takes 100%* --> because you specified a min value for an element having a default width equal to 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name suggests `min-width` means that the element will have atleast 30% width relative to its parent ( can be 30% and more upto 100%) . Since `div` is a block level element, it wants to take up the complete space available to it, and it'll expand to 100%.

`width:30%;` will specifically limit the element to only 30%.

You could also use `max-width` to limit the width to a certain number. Here `max-width: 30%` will give you the same result as the width will be atmost 30% relative to its parent.

Hope this helps and clears things up !

Answer (score 0):

Because it is working correctly. Block elements take full width of their parent, which, in this case, is `<body>`. Min-width doesn't constrain it in any way.
You can check the reference here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width

Answer (score 0):

Well... Property "min-width" is working as intended. You've specified a MINIMUM amount of space, that your element is allowed to take. So for example:

```
<style>
   .min-wdith--element {
       min-width: 30%;
       width: 100px;
   }
</style>
```

Element with .min-width--element class will take a minimum of 30% of a parent element, despite fact it "width" property is set to 100 pixels. What you're probably looking for is an "max-width" property, which will disallow and element to acquire more space than 30% of a parent element, no matter how wide the element is.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width